# Dont understand how to evaluate this Integral (Trigonometry)

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

So, im studying for my calculus exam and I just got to this Integral:

$$
\int _0^{2\pi }\int _1^24r^2\cos^3\left(\theta \right)+4r^3\cos\left(\theta \right)\sin^2\left(\theta \right)\,dr\,d\theta
$$

The problem I have is on the 'inner' integral.

I can calculate the indefinite integral and I know it is

$$
\frac{4}{3}r^3\cos ^3\left(θ\right)+r^4\sin ^2\left(θ\right)\cos \left(θ\right)+C
$$

But when I plug the interval (1 to 2) I get an "ugly" result. [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/integral-calculator/%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D%5Cint_%7B1%7D%5E%7B2%7D4r%5E%7B2%7Dcos%5Cleft(%5Ctheta%5Cright)%5E%7B3%7D%2B4r%5E%7B3%7Dcos%5Cleft(%5Ctheta%5Cright)sin%5Cleft(%5Ctheta%5Cright)%5E%7B2%7Ddrd%5Ctheta%20/?origin=button) tells me the result should be:

$$
-\frac{4}{3}\left(\cos \left(3θ\right)-9\cos \left(θ\right)\right)-\frac{1}{12}\left(15\cos \left(θ\right)+\cos \left(3θ\right)\right)
$$

And, after simplification, $\frac{43\cos \left(θ\right)}{4}-\frac{17}{12}\cos \left(3θ\right)$

But how? There's some trigonometric relation that I am not understanding here. Where did that $ \left(\cos \left(3θ\right)-9\cos \left(θ\right)\right) $ came from? What happened to the $\sin ^2\left(θ\right)$?

Comment: The $\cos 3\theta$ undoubtedly comes from the fact that $\cos 3\theta = \cos^3\theta - 3\sin^2\theta\cos\theta$. Symbolic integrators often do things like that, which are not things we would normally do in such an integration.

Comment: As a side note, the purpose of this problem is most likely to get you to realize that if you switch the order of integration, the problem becomes *much* easier.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left[\frac{4}{3}r^3\cos ^3 \theta+r^4\sin ^2 \theta \cos \theta\right]_1^2=\
\frac{4}{3}\left(7\cos^3 \theta \right)+15\sin^2 \theta \cos \theta=
$$
$$
\frac{28}{3}\cos^3 \theta+15 (1-\cos^2 \theta)\cos \theta=-\frac{17}{3}\cos^3 \theta+15\cos \theta
$$

Now use: $$\cos 3 \theta=4\cos^3 \theta-3\cos \theta$$

( this is the trigonometric relation!) and you have the result.